# How to lock down an entire Rails app until a User completes their account set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, actioncontroller, clearance

I have a rails app that uses the [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) for signup and login. After signup the user is redirected to `accounts/new` to complete their account setup. The Account `belongs_to` User and the user `has_one` account. (The Account and User models are separate because there are attributes, such as "Company Name" that I don't want to put into the User model.)

I'd like to lock down everything in the application and redirect them to `accounts/new` if they try to access anything other than marketing pages, signup, and login pages before they've created an Account.

I'm thinking that adding a `before_action` to the ApplicationController is the right approach and then using `:skip_before_action` on any `controller#action` that they need access before creating their Account (such as /signup or /login or marketing pages).

This seems like the right approach since the entire application will be locked down by default if the User hasn't created an account. By explicitly using using `:skip_before_action` as needed it seems like there is less of a chance of creating holes in the application by mistake.

But I can't get the `before_action` on the ApplicationController to work because I keep getting this error when I visit a page like /signup:

```
NoMethodError in Clearance::UsersController#new
undefined method `account' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Controller
  before_action :require_login
  before_action :require_account

  private

  def require_account
    if current_user.account != nil
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

That syntax worked when I was inside my AccountsController and just redirecting my `accounts#new` action, but now I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the same behavior across my entire application. Note: `current_user` is a method supplied by Clearance.

What is the "Rails way" to do this?

Comment: What about [SignInGuard](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#extending-sign-in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I consider you're in the right way to do it in 'Ruby on Rails way'!

The error `NoMethodError` is caused because inside some contexts of your application you **don't have** the `current_user` method.

If you **want to redirect the user to `dashboard_path` when the current_user already have the account**, you should try the following:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Controller
  before_action :require_login
  before_action :require_account

  private

  def require_account
    if current_user && current_user.account.present?
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

This way you can get the redirect when `current_user is present` **AND** `current_user have one account`, no `skip_before_action` is needed.

Comment: I think the condition can be shortened to `if current_user&.account`

Comment: Good comment! I write `current_user && current_user.account.present?` only to improve the reading, in a real case I prefer the `if current_user&.account`!

Comment: Thanks! The intended behavior is actually `if current_user && current_user.account.blank?` but this definitely helped me get there. Here's the Application Controller that I ended up with - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/68ca89f3c9e193266c9b9d9287263978. And the Accounts Controller https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/78efdde8efd092c24e754e021788ec4e. Also, another "gotcha" that was causing problems is I had to update my route from `get '/signup' => 'clearance/users#new', as: 'sign_up'` to `get '/signup' => 'users#new', as: 'sign_up'` so that I could skip the before action on signup/login.